# WinSCP .NET Assembly custom list that defines ASCII transfer when TransferMode == Automatic

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

This is a solution if you want to control which files will automatically be transferred by ASCII or BINARY without writing control statements for WinSCP in C#, you have to create a new session and on that session

```
AddRawConfiguration(@"Interface\CopyParam\Masks", ...)
```

For example:

```
using (var session = new Session())
{
    var asciiFileMasks = "*.xsl; *.xslt; *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml";
    session.AddRawConfiguration(@"Interface\CopyParam\Masks", asciiFileMasks );//for automatic transfers, this list determines ascii or binary mode

   ///... do your thing
}
```

Comment: You can *ask a question here*, then answer it below.  Stack Overflow isn't a blog, it's a Q&A website.

Comment: When you are in text mode, ftp replaces the return characters based on the operating system.  So if you are going from linux to windows the you need to use text mode.  In binary mode no changes are made.  So always use binary mode except when you are transferring text between different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is using [`TransferOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions_addrawsettings). Among other it does not need opening a new session:

```
var options = new TransferOptions();
options.AddRawSettings("Masks", "*.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; ...");
```

And you of course need to enable [automatic transfer mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#transfermode):

```
options.TransferMode = TransferMode.Automatic;
```

Then you use your `options` instance with methods like [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles), [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles), etc.